# Can I define a private template function outside of a class?

Tags: c++, function, templates, private, public

I have two template functions, `generatePerms` and `permute` in a header file (not for a class, just a general header file with utility-type functions). I want `generatePerms` to be publicly accessible, but `permute` should not be. Is there any way to do this? I don't think I can use `public:` and `private` outside of a class, but maybe there's a way to structure the header file that can achieve this end?

Example header file:

```
//header.hpp
#ifndef H_UTILITY
#define H_UTILITY

#include <vector>

//this one should be private
template <typename T>
void permute( std::vector<T> values, int n, std::vector<T> *perms ){ /* do stuff */ }

//this one should be public
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> generatePerms( std::vector<T> values, int n ){ /* do stuff, calls permute() */ }

#endif
```

Comment: If you don't want a function to be publicly available, don't declare it in the .h file and make it static in the .cpp file.

Comment: Also, I would simply put the functions you want to hide in some `namespace impl_Whatever` and tell the user not to go there. If he doesn't listen, it's his problem.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen its your problem as well if you want a nice code base.

Comment: @marsh I see no problem with `namespace myLib{ /*public stuff*/ namespace impl{ /*Hidden stuff*/}}`. I do not think some "hack" using classes would make that any better.

Comment: @MichaelWalz This is not so easy since it is a template to be called by another template function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the functions in a Util class as static functions like this

```
//header.hpp
#ifndef _H_UTIL_
#define _H_UTIL_

#include <vector>
class Util
{
    private:
    template <typename T>
    static void permute( std::vector<T> values, int n, std::vector<T> *perms ){ /* do stuff */ }

    public:
    template <typename T>
    static std::vector<T> generatePerms( std::vector<T> values, int n ){ /* do stuff, calls permute() */ }
};
#endif
```

and use the public function with
`Util::generatePerms(...)`.
(If you don't want to write Util::generatePerms(...) you can wrap it in a global function, though I would not recommend it.)

Comment: I'd make it `class detail` with `friend generatePerms` myself: don't stick `generatePerms` the publicly-used type in a `class`.  Ie, `namespace Util { class details{ ` ...  `};` ... `generatePerms( `... `) {` ... `}}`.

Answer (score 2):

A common technique is to put the function(s) in a namespace called something like `impl` or `detail`:

```
namespace my_ns {
namespace detail {
  void permute() {}
}

void generatePerm() {
  using namespace detail;
  ...
  permute();
  ...
}
}
```

It doesn't polute your namespace (so it doesn't show at user auto-complete) and is universally accepted that anything inside this kind of namespace is internal to the library and should not be touched.

Another option is to make them static functions:

```
class GlobalWhatever {
  private:
    static void permute() {}

  public:
    static void generatePerm() {}
};
```